# How can i use get token using react+firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, redux-saga

```
export function* login(auth, action){
try{
    const {signInWithEmailAndPassword} = auth
    const {email, password} = action.user
    const user = yield call([auth, signInWithEmailAndPassword], email, password)
    const {ra} = user.user
    yield auth.verifyIdToken(ra)
        .then(function(decodedToken) {
            let uid = decodedToken.uid
            console.log(uid)
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log('error no token')
        })
    /*
    axios.post('/api/token', { i really need to call a cloud function?
        ra
    }).then(data => data.data)
    */
    yield put(ActionCreator.signinSuccess(user.user))
}catch({message}){
    yield put(ActionCreator.signinFailure("Dind't have possible do login"))
}        
}
```

My doubt is this: when I log in to the firebase, I get a token, which stays in the variable 'user.user.ra'. To be able to use this token in my requests to the firebase realtime database, do I need to send that token to a cloud function to do the validation, or can I use some method in my own react to do this? In the firebase site, you have the method `admin.auth().VerifyIdToken(idToken)` to do this validation, but I can not use it in my saga. How should I do?

Comment: Do you have some custom backend server? If you're just interacting with firebase's database directly, i don't think you need to worry about the tokens. Once you've done signInWithEmailAndPassword, just use the methods here to communicate with the database: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

Comment: @NicholasTower , i am using just firebase for my backend. admin.auth() for authentication and realtime for database. 
I believe it is good to use tokens to ensure the security of my application, since when I log in I get the token and the refresh token. I configured the database rules in firebase, where only that is authenticated can access certain data, and only the user that is logged in that can change their data, such as email and password. But I believe the token is still needed to make it safer.

Comment: @NicholasTower, 
I know that the right place to verify the token is not in the login, because when I log in the token is valid, it was just to test the function verifyIdToken. This verification is done in methods that interact with the database, because if the token is not valid, this interaction will not occur